# Spring Security login issue, cookies

Tags: spring, cookies, spring-security

I have a problem with my spring application. My Spring Security config looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class CRManSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
            .usersByUsernameQuery("select sys_users.login, "
                    + "sys_users.password_hash, sys_users.enabled from sys_users where sys_users.login=?")
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select u.login, x.role_name from sys_users as u inner join (\n"
                    + "select * from sys_roles) as x on x.user_id = u.user_id where u.login=?;");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/resources/**", "login?status=logout").permitAll();
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
            .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/activities")
            .usernameParameter("j_username")
            .passwordParameter("j_password")
            .failureUrl("/login?status=error")
            .and().logout().logoutUrl("/logout")
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?status=logout")
            .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403")
            .and().csrf().disable();

}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    PasswordEncoder encoder = new Cryptographer();
    return encoder;
}

}
```

I cannot login when I have cookie JSESSIONID in my browser. It always return me to the login page.
But once I delete this cookie manually it works fine until next logout.

It also works when I remove

> .anyRequest().authenticated()

But I need to prevent every unauthorized request except resource access.

Have you any ideas about this issue?

UPD 1.

[DEBUG logs](http://pastebin.com/sZGJQPyd)

Comment: Can you post the debug logs? Do you have multiple JSESSIONID cookies? Have you customized the HttpSession using something like Spring Session?

Comment: Please see update. I have just one cookie in my browser and it prevent me from login, until I delete it manually (it works fine for very first time, when this cookie is not set by tomcat yet) . No, I haven't.

Comment: I don't see anywhere in the logs where a POST was submitted to /j_spring_security_check. Can you please ensure to enable the debug logs and post only the logs for when you submit a username / password and it fails? Preferably only logs for org.springframework.*

Answer (score 0):

```
.defaultSuccessUrl("/activities", true)
```

Parameter true works for me